# Wi-fi connection times out in a strange way

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook-pro

I have a Linksys Wireless-N Home ADSL2+ router to which I connect my MacBook Pro. The thing is that the connection behaves strangely. Let me explain: from time to time, the internet connection times out (on daily basis, more than once a day); the laptop doesn’t disconnect from the router, but I just can’t connect to internet anymore. To solve this I either turn off and back on AirPort or switch to a different network and then back to mine. In both cases, the issue disappears when I switch back.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Router: Linksys Wireless-N Home ADSL2+ (model WAG120N)
Laptop: MacBook Pro spring 2011
OS: 10.6.8
ISP: Libero (Italy—if it might be important in connection with the router model)

Comment: Three questions: 1) What wireless encryption mode are you using? 2) Are you sure you have proper DSL filters in place. 3) Are you positive you can still ping the router (or reach its web interface) when you can't reach the Internet?

Comment: What is the channel setting?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 1) WPA2 Personal; 2) I don’t know what that is; 3) To be honest, I haven’t checked. (I’ll check and get back to you.)

Comment: @Dez Wide Channel: 9; Standard Channel: 11 2.462 GHz

Comment: @Alex k, just making sure you weren't using the `auto` setting since that can cause constant timeouts (personal experience)

Comment: If you aren't sure if you have proper DSL filters in place, that's probably the problem. When you have DSL, you must have either a "whole house splitter" at the point of entry or a filter at *every* telephone jack or where every device is connected to the phone line, including things like alarm systems, satellite TV receivers, and so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a splitter at the phone jack, yes. Also, regarding question no. 3, no, the router doesn’t respond at ping, but the AirPort status indicator shows it as being connected.

Comment: A splitter at the phone jack is *not* a splitter at the point of entry. That means you need a filter at *every* other phone jack or device connected to the phone line. That includes the things you forget are connected to the phone line, like alarm systems and satellite TV receivers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There aren’t any other devices connected, just one phone and the router. The TV is on a completely different line.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the Linksys WAG120N is occasionally screwing up group key rotation, and thus can't get ARP requests to your MacBook Pro, so after its ARP cache times out the entry for your MacBook Pro, it can't forward packets to you any more. To test this theory, the next time your MacBook Pro gets into this state, put another machine on your wireless network (or on a LAN port of the WAG120N) and have it ping the "all hosts" multicast address: 224.0.0.1. If your MacBook Pro responds, it's getting multicasts. If it doesn't, then it isn't. Also try pinging 224.0.0.1 from your MacBook Pro and see if anything else responds. It would be an interesting data point.

Make sure you have the latest firmware on your WAG120N. Consider adding a static ARP mapping on your WAG120N pointing to your MacBook Pro (you'd also need to assign your MacBook Pro a static IP address as well). Consider putting aftermarket/third-party/open-source firmware on your WAG120N in case the open source firmware is higher quality than what Linksys provides.

Comment: It has the latest firmware version. (At list, the official one from Linksys—1.00.16.)

Comment: Also, it seems that this model doesn’t support DHCP reservation.